# Multiple Polynomial fits in ggplot using facetwrap

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I would like to use multiple polynomial curves to fit 2 dimensional data,
I am able to plot one polynomial function but I would like to use for example 4 and then plot all of them at the same time using `facet_wrap`.

Now I am using simple 2 order polynomial:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- mtcars
df <- data.frame("x"=df$mpg, "y"=df$hp)


my.formula <- y ~ x + I(x^2)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(shape=21, fill="blue", colour="black", size=2, alpha = 0.7) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F, 
                     formula = my.formula, 
                     colour = "red")

m <- lm(my.formula, df)
my.eq <- as.character(signif(as.polynomial(coef(m)), 3))
label.text <- paste(gsub("x", "~italic(x)", my.eq, fixed = TRUE),
                    paste("italic(R)^2",  
                          format(summary(m)$r.squared, digits = 2), 
                          sep = "~`=`~"),
                    sep = "~~~~")

p + annotate(geom = "text", label = label.text, 
             family = "serif", hjust = 0, parse = TRUE, size = 4)
```

lets say we would like to use another formulas such as:

```
my.formula2 <- y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3)
my.formula4 <- y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3) + I(x^4)
my.formula5 <- y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3) + I(x^4) + I(x^5)
```

And plot it in the base plot above using `facet_wrap` so we would have 4 seperate plots and each has to have its own label text and anotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer that first fits polynomial regression and gets the predicted values, then plots them all with `geom_line`, not `geom_smooth`.

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- mtcars
df <- data.frame("x"=df$mpg, "y"=df$hp)

tmp <- sapply(2:5, function(d){
  predict(lm(y ~ poly(x, d), df))
})
df2 <- df
df2 <- cbind(df2, tmp)
rm(tmp)
names(df2)[-(1:2)] <- paste0("degree", 2:5)
long <- reshape2::melt(df2, id.vars = c("x", "y"))

ggplot(long, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(shape=21, fill="blue", colour="black", size=2, alpha = 0.7) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = value), colour = "red") +
  facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

[image]

## Edit.

Another way, without fitting the models previously, is the following, inspired in a [RStudio community post](https://community.rstudio.com/t/ggplot-change-k-in-gam-formula-of-geom-smooth/1948/3).

```
library(tidyverse)

cbind(df, tmp) %>%
  gather(degree, value, -x, -y) %>%
  {
    reduce2(.init = ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y)),
            .x = .$degree,
            .y = .$value,
            function(prev, .x, .y) {
              force(.y) # The formula below won't evaluate .y by itself
              prev + geom_smooth(
                data = . %>% filter(degree == .x),
                method = "lm",
                se = FALSE,
                formula = y ~ poly(x, .y))
            })
  } +
  geom_point(fill = "blue", colour = "black",size = 2, alpha = 0.7) +
  facet_wrap(~ degree)
```

Comment: great use of sapply, I applaud you sir.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple with the `stat_function` function

I know you said you wanted to use `facet_wrap` but I would suggest using `ggarrange` in the `ggpubr` library

```
mylm1 <- lm(hp ~ mpg + I(mpg^2), data = df)
mylm2 <- lm(hp ~ mpg + I(mpg^2) + I(mpg^3), data = df)
mylm3 <- lm(hp ~ mpg + I(mpg^2) + I(mpg^3) + I(mpg^4), data = df)
mylm4 <- lm(hp ~ mpg + I(mpg^2) + I(mpg^3) + I(mpg^4) + I(mpg^5), data = df)



b1 <- coef(mylm1)
b2 <- coef(mylm2)
b3 <- coef(mylm3)
b4 <- coef(mylm4)




p1 <- df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) b1[1] + b1[2]*x + b1[3]*x^2) 

p2 <- df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) b2[1] + b2[2]*x + b2[3]*x^2 + b2[4]*x^3) 

p3 <- df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +  
  stat_function(fun = function(x) b3[1] + b3[2]*x + b3[3]*x^2 + b3[4]*x^3 + b3[5]*x^4) 

p4 <- df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +  
  stat_function(fun = function(x) b4[1] + b4[2]*x + b4[3]*x^2 + b4[4]*x^3 + b4[5]*x^4 + b4[6]*x^5)


library(ggpubr)

ggarrange(p1,p2,p3,p4)
```

[image]

Comment: This is not exactly it - I wanted it to use `facet_wrap` function so we would have 4 plots (2 rown 2 columns)

Comment: Thank it is essentialy the same as using `grid.arrange` function wich I am familiar with - that is why I posted question

Comment: The issue is that you want and I quote "four separate plots, and each has its own label, text, and annotation." It would be extremely time consuming to do this with `facet_wrap` as in reality it creates one plot, with the same aesthetics, i.e., label, text, and annotation. I think using `grid.arrange` or `ggarrange` is the way to go for what you want. You'll be able to manipulate each plot as you see fit, without interfering with the other 3.